# In Craft CMS CP plugin, how can I intercept the lightswitch.php getTableAttributeHtml?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm trying to make a basic plugin that intercepts Lightswitch.php and edits getTableAttributeHtml

Here is the current way:

```
public function getTableAttributeHtml(mixed $value, ElementInterface $element): string
    {
        if (!$value) {
            return '';
        }
        
        $label = $this->onLabel ?: Craft::t('app', 'Enabled');

        return Html::tag('span', '', [
            'class' => 'checkbox-icon',
            'role' => 'img',
            'title' => $label,
            'aria' => [
                'label' => $label,
            ],
        ]);
    }
```

I want it to do something like this:

```
public function getTableAttributeHtml(mixed $value, ElementInterface $element): string
    {
        if (!$value) {
            //return '';
            return Html::tag('span', '', [
                'class' => 'checkbox-icon unchecked',
                'fieldname' => $this->handle
            ]);
        }
        
        $label = $this->onLabel ?: Craft::t('app', 'Enabled');

        return Html::tag('span', '', [
            'class' => 'checkbox-icon',
            'role' => 'img',
            'title' => $label,
            'aria' => [
                'label' => $label,
            ],
            'fieldname' => $this->handle
        ]);
    }
```

Trying to make a global plugin that does this

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, place this code in the website main module class:

```
use craft\base\Element;
use craft\events\SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent;
use yii\base\Event;
use craft\helpers\Html;
```

```
        Event::on(
            Element::class,
            Element::EVENT_SET_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE_HTML,
            function (SetElementTableAttributeHtmlEvent $event) {

                $fieldHandle = 'someField';
                $field = Craft::$app->fields->getFieldByHandle($fieldHandle);
                if(is_null($field)){
                    return;
                }
                if(get_class($field) != 'craft\fields\Lightswitch'){
                    return;
                }
                if($event->attribute != ('field:' . $field->uid)){
                    return;
                }

                $value = $event->sender->getFieldValue($fieldHandle);
                if (!$value) {
                    $event->html = Html::tag('span', '', [
                        'class' => 'checkbox-icon unchecked',
                        'fieldname' => $field->handle
                    ]);
                }else{
                    $label = $field->onLabel ?: Craft::t('app', 'Enabled');
                    $event->html = Html::tag('span', '', [
                        'class' => 'checkbox-icon',
                        'role' => 'img',
                        'title' => $label,
                        'aria' => [
                            'label' => $label,
                        ],
                        'fieldname' => $field->handle
                    ]);
                }



            }
        );
```